# Restoring backups

Tags: windows-live

So, my phone has been off for repair - the graphics failed (well, after it met a concrete floor...), so I wasn't able to do a manual backup before I sent it off.

I've now got it back, and turned it on, and went through the set up - I didn't sign into my Live account at that stage. I started changing settings, and signed into my Live account - at which point I realised it had synced all my texts (which I assumed had been lost!); after some Googling, I realised that other settings are saved, but only synced if you sign in when you set the phone up... so I did a factory reset, signed in to my live account, waited patiently, and my original settings weren't there (in fact, neither were the ones I'd set about 15 mins earlier).

So... did my phone make a backup in the interim? And if so, am I being too optimistic that I'm able to get a past backup?!

**EDIT**

In fact, I've just realised I wasn't given an option to select a backup - is there a way to force the setup sequence to show backups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was running an out-of-date 8.0 build; I'm not sure when app lists / settings started to be included in backups but I'm pretty sure from what I've played around with that the build I had didn't do it.  I'm currently running the latest version of 8.0 and app lists / settings are included.